# Web API HMAC Authentication- Intermittent 404 Not Found Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2, hmac

I'm following the HMAC authentication approach as outlined [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/12/15/secure-asp-net-web-api-using-api-key-authentication-hmac-authentication/) in a Web Api application that's deployed on Azure but I'm running into 404 errors more than half the time on the same HTTP GET calls.

It seems that when I make the invocation to the server, even though my request URI is of the format,

```
http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/api/foo/bar?val=123
```

Around half the time, the request URI in the HttpResponseMessage comes back as

```
http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fval%3D123
```

This only happens when I apply the HMACAuthentication attribute on my foo controller.

The strange part is that it doesn't happen every time and doesn't happen when I run on localhost. I've copied out the example exactly from the github repo. I was thinking the server time might have something to do with this, but that doesn't explain why the requests go through sometimes and fail at others... it should be consistent. Not sure what part of the code is relevant to put down here either so please let me know what'd help to see.

I'd appreciate any insight on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the problem was occurring in the *isReplayRequest* method in the repo.

Here's the original method definition:

```
    private bool isReplayRequest(string nonce, string requestTimeStamp)
    {
        if (System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Contains(nonce))
        {
            return true;
        }

        DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        TimeSpan currentTs = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;

        var serverTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(currentTs.TotalSeconds);
        var requestTotalSeconds = Convert.ToUInt64(requestTimeStamp);

        if ((serverTotalSeconds - requestTotalSeconds) > requestMaxAgeInSeconds)
        {
            return true;
        }

        System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache.Default.Add(nonce, requestTimeStamp, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(requestMaxAgeInSeconds));

        return false;
    }
```

The issue was occurring at the second if condition where the serverTotalSeconds and requestTotalSeconds are **unsigned integers.**

There were periodic cases where the timestamps would end up negative (i.e. the requestTotalSeconds was greater than serverTotalSeconds by 1), which would end up setting the value of (serverTotalSeconds - requestTotalSeconds) as 18446744073709551615, which is the max value UInt64 can hold.

In my case, I used two TimeSpan objects to compare the time and derive the difference in seconds.

Hope this helps someone else.